# android MediaRecorder(): start failed: -2147483648

Tags: android, camera, onresume, mediarecorder

I am facing problems with android camera recording, the issue is whenever I record the video and go to videoPlayer activity to view the video and after I finish the videoPlayer activity and coming back to my videoRecrding activity if I start capturing the video again with back camera it gives me the exception mentioned in the title of this post, if the camera was in FRONT mode before going to videoPlayer activity it behaves normal and records again normally but the only problem is with BACK CAMERA.
here my `videoRecorder` activity

```
public class VideoRecorder extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnErrorListener
{
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    private static int CURRENT_CAMERA_ID; 
    public static int VIDEO_QUALITY = CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH;

    public static boolean CAMERA_FLASH_AVAILABLE = false;
    public static boolean FRONT_CAMERA_AVAILABLE = false;
    public static boolean EXTERNAL_STORAGE_AVAILABLE = false;

    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

    private int VIDEO_RECORDING_LIMIT = 60; 

    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private String TAG = "CustmoizedCamera Application";
    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private Parameters cameraParams;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private TextView TextViewRecordingPercentage;
    private ProgressBar ProgressBarVideoRecording;
    private StorageHelper mStorageHelper;
    public File VideoPath;
    ImageButton ImageButtonVideoRecordingCapture, ImageButtonVideoRecordingFlash, ImageButtonVideoRecordingSwapCamera, ImageButtonVideoRecordingClose, ImageButtonVideoRecordingUpload, ImageButtonVideoRecordingThumbnail;
    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback()
    {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                ImageButtonVideoRecordingThumbnail.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath()));

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.d("inside onCreate", "of VideoRecorder");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_recording_layout);
        mStorageHelper = new StorageHelper();

        CAMERA_FLASH_AVAILABLE = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
        FRONT_CAMERA_AVAILABLE = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT);
        EXTERNAL_STORAGE_AVAILABLE = mStorageHelper.isExternalStorageAvailable();

//      mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        ImageButtonVideoRecordingFlash = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button_video_recording_flash);
        ImageButtonVideoRecordingSwapCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button_video_recording_swap_camera);
        ImageButtonVideoRecordingClose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button_video_recording_close);
        ImageButtonVideoRecordingUpload = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button_video_recording_upload);
        ImageButtonVideoRecordingCapture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button_video_recording_capture);
        ImageButtonVideoRecordingThumbnail = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button_video_recording_thumbnail);

        CURRENT_CAMERA_ID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("cam_id");
        if(CURRENT_CAMERA_ID == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
        {
            ImageButtonVideoRecordingFlash.setClickable(false);
            VIDEO_QUALITY = CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW;
        }

        ProgressBarVideoRecording = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_video_recording);

        TextViewRecordingPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_video_recording_percentage);

//      mCamera = getCameraInstance(CURRENT_CAMERA_ID);
//      
//      if(mCamera != null)
//      {
//          mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(getApplicationContext(), mCamera);
//          ImageButtonVideoRecordingThumbnail.setOnClickListener(null);
//          ProgressBarVideoRecording.setProgress(0);
//          TextViewRecordingPercentage.setText("60");
//          FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
//          preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
//      }
//      else
//      {
//          Log.d("inside onCreate", "Camera = null");
//      }
//      mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(getApplicationContext(), mCamera);
//
//      FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
//      preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

        ImageButtonVideoRecordingCapture.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButtonVideoRecordingFlash.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButtonVideoRecordingSwapCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButtonVideoRecordingClose.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButtonVideoRecordingUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
//      ImageButtonVideoRecordingThumbnail.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public Camera getCameraInstance(int camId)
    {
        Camera c = null;
        CURRENT_CAMERA_ID = camId;
        if(CURRENT_CAMERA_ID == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
        {
            VIDEO_QUALITY = CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW;
            ImageButtonVideoRecordingFlash.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            VIDEO_QUALITY = CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH;
            ImageButtonVideoRecordingFlash.setEnabled(true);
        }
        try
        {
            c = Camera.open(camId); // attempt to get a Camera instance
//          c = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }
    private void releaseMediaRecorder()
    {
        if (mMediaRecorder != null)
        {
            mMediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera()
    {
        if (mCamera != null)
        {
            mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private static Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
        int cameraCount = 0;
        Camera cam = null;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) 
        {
            Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
            if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT  ) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
                }
                catch (RuntimeException e) 
                {
//                  Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        return cam;
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type)
    {
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists())
        {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs())
            {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)
        {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator+ "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        }
        else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator+ "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder()
    {

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.lock();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(this);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        // mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(VIDEO_QUALITY));

        // Step 4: Set output file
        VideoPath = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(VideoPath.toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try
        {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: "+ e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.image_button_video_recording_capture:
                if(EXTERNAL_STORAGE_AVAILABLE)
                {
                    if (isRecording)
                    {
                        // stop recording and release camera
                        try
                        {
                            mMediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                            mCamera.lock(); // take camera access back from
                            // MediaRecorder
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // inform the user that recording has stopped
                        isRecording = false;
                        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                        ImageButtonVideoRecordingCapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_video_recording_unselected);
                        ImageButtonVideoRecordingSwapCamera.setClickable(true);
                        ImageButtonVideoRecordingThumbnail.setOnClickListener(VideoRecorder.this);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Video saved to SD Card\\Pictures\\MyCameraApp ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // initialize video camera
                        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(VIDEO_RECORDING_LIMIT * 1000, 1000)
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                            {
                                updateRecordingPercentage((int) millisUntilFinished/1000);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish()
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    mMediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                                    releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                                    mCamera.lock(); // take camera access back from
                                    // MediaRecorder
                                    updateRecordingPercentage(0);
                                }
                                catch(Exception ex)
                                {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                // inform the user that recording has stopped
                                isRecording = false;
                                ImageButtonVideoRecordingCapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_video_recording_unselected);
                                ImageButtonVideoRecordingSwapCamera.setClickable(true);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Video saved to SD Card\\Pictures\\MyCameraApp ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        };
//                      mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                        if (prepareVideoRecorder())
                        {
                            // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is
                            // prepared,
                            // now you can start recording
                            mMediaRecorder.start();
                            // inform the user that recording has started
                            isRecording = true;
                            mCountDownTimer.start();
                            ImageButtonVideoRecordingSwapCamera.setClickable(false);
                            ImageButtonVideoRecordingCapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_video_recording_selected);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                            releaseMediaRecorder();
                            // inform user
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD card not available.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.image_button_video_recording_close:
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                releaseCamera();
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.image_button_video_recording_flash:
                if(!isRecording)
                {
                    if (CAMERA_FLASH_AVAILABLE)
                    {
                        cameraParams = mCamera.getParameters();
                        if (cameraParams.getFlashMode().equalsIgnoreCase(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
                        {
                            cameraParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                            mCamera.setParameters(cameraParams);
                            ImageButtonVideoRecordingFlash.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_video_recording_flash_selected);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cameraParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                            mCamera.setParameters(cameraParams);
                            ImageButtonVideoRecordingFlash.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_video_recording_flash_unselected);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera flash not available.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
                break;
            case R.id.image_button_video_recording_swap_camera:
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                if(FRONT_CAMERA_AVAILABLE)
                {
                    if(CURRENT_CAMERA_ID == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    {
                        startActivity(intent.putExtra("cam_id", CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        startActivity(intent.putExtra("cam_id", CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK));
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.image_button_video_recording_upload:
                break;
            case R.id.image_button_video_recording_thumbnail:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, VideoPlayer.class).putExtra("video_path", VideoPath.getAbsolutePath()));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // super.onBackPressed();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        releaseCamera();
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
    private void updateRecordingPercentage(int orgPerc)
    {
        TextViewRecordingPercentage.setText(orgPerc+"");
        ProgressBarVideoRecording.setProgress(VIDEO_RECORDING_LIMIT- orgPerc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        Log.d("inside", "onPause() of Video recorder");
        super.onPause();
        if(mCamera != null)
        {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCameraPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mCameraPreview);
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it
                                    // first
            releaseCamera(); // release the camera immediately on pause event
        }
    }


//  @Override
//  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
//  {
//      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//      Log.d("inside", "onActivityResult of video recorder");
//      Intent mIntent = getIntent();
//      finish();
//      startActivity(mIntent);
//  }

    @Override
    public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Log.d("MediaRecorderError " + what, "" + extra);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onResume()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance(CURRENT_CAMERA_ID);

        if(mCamera != null)
        {
            mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(getApplicationContext(), mCamera);
            ImageButtonVideoRecordingThumbnail.setOnClickListener(null);
            ProgressBarVideoRecording.setProgress(0);
            TextViewRecordingPercentage.setText("60");
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("inside onCreate", "Camera = null");
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my `CameraPreview` class

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
    private final String TAG = "Customized Camera Application"; 
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Parameters mParameters;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) 
    {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try 
        {
            CamcorderProfile mProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(VideoRecorder.VIDEO_QUALITY);  
            mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            mParameters.setPreviewSize(mProfile.videoFrameWidth, mProfile.videoFrameHeight);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            mCamera.release();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        try 
        {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) 
    {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)
        {
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try 
        {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try 
        {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

here is my stacktrace

```
01-22 15:01:52.328: I/MediaRecorderJNI(1045): prepare: surface=0x5e7736e0
01-22 15:01:52.383: E/MediaRecorder(1045): start failed: -2147483648
01-22 15:01:52.383: D/AndroidRuntime(1045): Shutting down VM
01-22 15:01:52.383: W/dalvikvm(1045): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4201a700)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.galaxonic.jmtv.VideoRecorder.onClick(VideoRecorder.java:385)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-22 15:01:52.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 15:02:02.477: I/Process(1045): Sending signal. PID: 1045 SIG: 9
```

I am stuck here.